# Нe открывается fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, moxy, navigation

Есть программа для работы со списками. 
По интерфейсу есть два основных окна, в одном лист со списками, и по клику со конкретному списку по подаем на экран с элементами списка.
Приложение представляет собой SingleActivity moxy+androidx.navigation+rxjava
Проблема возникает при следующем кейсе. 
Я  открываю deeplink в мессанжере, скачиваю новые данные из firebase, сохраняю данные в room и после этого автоматом пытаюсь уже перейти на новый фрагмент
Вот так не работает

```
     model.saveShop(dlDl, currentDlId).observeOn(mainThread)
        .subscribe { list->
            goToList(listId = list.id!!)}}
```

А вот так уже работает

```
 model.saveShop(dlShop, currentDlId).observeOn(mainThread)
        .subscribe { list->
            Single
                .timer(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
               .observeOn(mainThread).subscribe { _->
                goToList(listId = list.id!!)
            }
           
        }
```

Пробовал во втором(проблемном фрагменте раставлять точки breakPoint и логи)
 В итоге по логам второй фрагмент пытается запускаться, метод onCreateView отрабатывает, в презетере attachView тоже отрабатывается, данные с загруженого листа в полной мере загружаются из базы данных, но логи раставленые в фрагменте на вызовы функций из презеттера типа viewState.doSomething() уже не вызываются
в логах нет ни единой ошибки или краша
Что может происходить такого, чтоб фрагмент в итоге не запускался.

Comment: Если метод onCreateView отрабатывает значит фрагмент всё таки запускается, предположу, что проблема в переключении потоков выполнения. Скорее всего достаточно добавить к методу goToList(listId = list.id!!).observeOn(mainThread) чтобы всё заработало.

Comment: так я же  прежде чем подписаться переключаю поток на главный тред. Да и onCreateView не в гланом потоке не запустилось

Comment: Оператор observeOn переключает поток выполнения условно для всех операций расположенных выше него в rx цепочке. То есть в вашем случае model.saveShop выполняется в главном потоке, а goToList в том, который указан в подписке subscribeOn (скорее всего это io)

Comment: С чего  observeOn  переключает операции выше?  Да, в subscribeOn у меня действительно io  и вся цепочка работает в этом шедулере пока не встретила observeOn  после этого поток переключился на главный тред и  лямда которая в subscribe  уже должна выполняться в главном потоке

Comment: Я не правильно выразился, я имел ввиду подписку самого метода  goToList. Какой код у вас в методе goToList, какие там потоки указаны?

Comment: там просто дергаться navcontroller.navigate() (стандартная навигация из androidx)

Comment: А вы пробовали моё предложение из 1 комментария - goToList(listId = list.id!!).observeOn(mainThread) без таймера?

Comment: goToList() это обычная функция, это не обзервер или на что повесить  или просто создать внутри подписки внутрений  single  без таймера?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110892/discussion-between-blind-falcon-and-tosh17).

Answer (score 0):

Room товарищ весьма умный, и часто позволяет себе асинхронность там, где может ее обеспечить. Тот факт что задержка в 100мс решает вашу проблему говорит мне, что вы столкнулись именно с таким поведением. Заставьте его притормозить прицепив к @Insert методу возвращаемое значение, должно помочь

```
@Dao
public interface SomeDao {
   @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
   fun addSome(Some object): Int
}
```

Теперь методу придется сначала выполнится целиком чтобы вернуть вам айдишник вставленного элемента. А на всякий случай я бы еще и клал это число в какую-то переменную и выводил в логи, а то Cursor из обычной библиотеки с SQLite вам возвращается почти мгновенно всегда, но данных в нем еще может не быть, т.к. они асинхроно добываются. И когда вы попытаетесь получить первую строчку подвисните на 300мс, а все последуюшщие будут читаться за 1мс. Вдруг тут каким-то образом тоже так сработает?

Comment: я тоже грешил, что может room не успевал записать, но в новом фрагменте, в презентере данные успешно грузились из room, именно те которые записывались, ну и id  у меня есть, его собственно я и передаю как аргумент в новый фрагмент